# json.loads changes order of the keys given in the string passed

Tags: python, json, django

```
 >>> x='{"Title":"test","Description":"test des","Colo":"test colo1","Expected Date":"1234","Comboboxes":"option1","Checkboxes":["option1","option2"]}'
 >>> x
'{"Title":"test","Description":"test des","Colo":"test colo1","Expected Date":"1234","Comboboxes":"option1","Checkboxes":["option1","option2"]}'
 >>> json.loads(x)
{'Expected Date': '1234', 'Description': 'test des', 'Title': 'test', 'Comboboxes': 'option1', 'Colo': 'test colo1', 'Checkboxes': ['option1', 'option2']}
```

Please help me to get these keys in the same order that of the given string.

Comment: JSON object keys are not ordered.

Comment: why do they need to be in the same order?

Comment: I m actually creating creating a dynamic form in django which stores the data in json format. Next time when the user needs to view the data, i need to parse through the json and display data in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

`json.loads()` produces a Python dictionary, which gets its ordering from internal hashing tables. You can use `sorted()` to sort them, but you cannot order a standard dictionary. You can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects), if needed.

Comment: I have tried that option also. Even ordereddict gives me the same order as json.loads

Comment: You can only output(i.e print/show) the dictionary as ordered but u cannot store a dictionary in order.